# How can i find the DHCP server?

Tags: windows, powershell, server, dhcp

i got a few domains and all of the servers\computers are without description

i tried to write a script that supost to retrieve network settings so i could find the DHCP server

(netsh show dhcp server and ipconfig /all didnt help at all)

```
$computers = get-adcomputer -filter {OperatingSystem -notlike "*Server*"} -properties OperatingSystem | sort name | format-table name,OperatingSystem
 foreach($computer in $computers){
 get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -computername $computer
}
```

Comment: If the DHCP servers are domain integrated you just need `Get-DhcpServerInDC`. Didn't you have this already?

Comment: this command doesn't work because there is no DHCP role on the server, and all the AD is so messy so i just cant  find the DHCP server so i could run get-dhcpserverindc

Comment: You have two ways you could do this.  First--this is the approach you're trying here--you could hit every machine in the environment, then query each machines network adapters looking for the IP of a DHCP Server.  This is a bad idea and really inefficient, unless you are looking for rogue DHCP servers, like home routers in the network.  The better approach is query AD for all Domain Integrated DHCP servers.